# How is the longest second-shortest path called?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In graph theory, the [diameter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) is the longest shortest path, i.e., if $d(u,v)$ stands for the distance (shortest path length) between $u$ and $v$, then the diameter is $D=\max_{u,v\in V}d(u,v)$.

Consider measuring how well a routing over a graph would do when a potential facing link failure.
For a pair of vertices $u,v$, let's define the *backup route* as the next-shortest path that is link-disjoint from the shortest path.
In case there are multiple shortest paths, let us pick a primary route that minimizes the length of the backup route.

(the primary must be an actual shortest path in the graph, we do not try to minimize their sum of lengths or any other metric).

So there are a few questions:

- If we denote the length of the backup route as $d_b(u,v)$, is there a name for the quantity $D_b=\max_{u,v\in v}d_b(u,v)$?
- Is there an efficient algorithm to compute $D_b$?

Intuitively, $D_b$ captures the worse case number of hops for any source/destination pair.
The goal would then be to consider designing graphs with $D_b\le x$ (for some integer $x$) with the smallest number of edges possible.

- Fixing the number of vertices in the graph $|V|=n$ and for some parameter $x\in\mathbb N^+$, what is the minimal size edge set $E$ such that $D_b\le x$?